# Could not install pandas_profiling packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, access-denied, pandas-profiling

I tried installing pandas_profiling in Jupyter Notebook and got the following error

```
!pip install pandas_profiling
```

[it throws an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDkeg.png)

I also tried this
"Run pip install pandas-profiling command in a separate cell in the jupyter notebook.
After this just restart the kernal and run again."
but still can't install pandas_profiling.

So How can I install it in the jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

I just had to type command 'pip install pandas_profiling' on my terminal and then restart kernal on jupyter notebook,then it started working.

I hope this helps anyone facing such problem in future

Thanks SO!